# How to pass API end point to update data with the help of AXIOS in React with query parameters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, axios

My API endpoint is “/api/user/self/, which accepts GET and PUT requests

For updating the user information, I need to make a PUT request with the user
document in the format as given below in JSON:

```
{
 "name": "Test",
 "communications": {
 "email": {
 "email": "test@user.com",
 "notifications": true
 },
 },
}
```

I've set the express like below:

```
   app.put("/api/user/self", (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = req.query;
       res.json({
        queryParams
      });
    });
```

Now I have to update data in my React component. I used AXIOS to fetch the data, like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/user/self")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setUser(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

I've been unable to use PUT request with AXIOS for updating the data from the front-end

I checked in the Postman for PUT method , and was able to see the change like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/user/self?name=test5
```

leads to:

```
{
    "queryParams": {
        "name": "test5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `axios.put(url, myData)` and the on the server to log the body of the request ? `console.log(req.body)` ? (Add `express.json()`)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.       console.log(req.body) gives me null  {} like undefined. Where should I use express.json( )?    Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: I elaborated in the answer, let me know if you need a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

To use PUT requests with axios (front) and express back you need to ensure the following:

- that express uses the json middleware which parse incoming JSON requests (for v4 [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)):

```js
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
```

- that axios use the PUT request with body:

```js
axios.put(url, myData)
```